# Is it "View on Facebook" or "View in Facebook"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

Which is correct: *View on Facebook* or *View in Facebook*?

Comment: I use on facebook

Comment: @mplungjan: *Everyone* uses "on Facebook".

Answer (score 0):

'On facebook'

I think it can be used in context similarly to how online is used to explain being 'on the line'

eg. I was watching live streams online